Overload resolution of const and non-const function fails on template
In the following code, when calling arr.begin() on a const Array<10> object, it fails to find the const function Accessor::begin() const, and instead only tries MutableAccessor::begin() and fails because arr is const.
When using arr.cbegin(), it works correctly.
Also when both the const and non-const overload of a function are defined in the same class, it works correctly.
I see that inside the definition of Array and MutableAccessor, begin() would be a dependent name on the template arguments, but what is the reason why when called from outside, MutableAccessor::begin() seems to have priority?
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t Size, class Derived>
struct Accessor {
    const int* begin() const { return this_()->array.data(); }
    const int* cbegin() const { return this_()->array.data(); }
    const Derived* this_() const { return static_cast<const Derived*>(this); }
};

template<std::size_t Size, class Derived>
struct MutableAccessor : Accessor<Size, Derived> {
    int* begin() { return this_()->array.data(); }
    Derived* this_() { return static_cast<Derived*>(this); }
};

template<std::size_t Size>
struct Array : MutableAccessor<Size, Array<Size>> {
    std::array<int, Size> array;
};

void f(const Array<10>& arr) {
    std::cout << *arr.begin() << std::endl;  // fails to find Accessor::begin()
}

int main() {
    Array<10> arr;
    f(arr);
}


using Accessor<Size, Derived>::begin; in MutableAccessor otherwise the begin there hides the one in its base. I'm not making it an answer because I won't be able to explain it correctly. Btw, the design is dubious: an array is not an accessor, thus the public inheritance is not the correct way to go and I don't see what you're gaining with two levels of indirection instead of a single one.

In the real code there is also an argument T, and MutableAccessor<T> inherits Accessor<const T>.
And there is an non-owning ArrayView class in addition to Array. There can be ArrayView<T> and ArrayView<const T>, and they only inherit Accessor<T> or Accessor<const T>.

Thus const ArrayView<T> always gives mutable access to its data. But [const?] Array<T> only gives mutable access if the Array itself is non-const.

It avoids having to re-implement all of the accessor functions. And avoids having Array inherit, contain or on-the-fly construct ArrayView<T> and/or ArrayView<const T>.

Technically an Array or ArrayView is something that allows access to array data, justifying the inheritance
